# mongodump results in Failed: can't create session: could not connect to server: connection() : dial tcp: i/o timeout

Tags: mongodb, macos, mongodb-atlas, mongodump

I am trying to backup a database from MongoDB Atlas.

When running the following `mongodump` command (with missing information of course):

```
mongodump --uri mongodb+srv://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<STUFF>.mongodb.net/<DATABASE>
```

I receive the following response:

```
Failed: can't create session: could not connect to server: connection() : dial tcp: i/o timeout
```

I have tried this command on another computers and it works fine so I'm pretty sure the error is not on the server end and has something to do with my computer (although I am able to `mongodump` a local database). I've also tried to `mongodump` other MongoDB Atlas databases on other accounts but receive same response.

`mongodump` was installed through homebrew following the [MongoDB installation documentation of `mongodb-community`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/). I've tried completely removing all mongodb related files on my system (including `mongodb-database-tools`) and reinstalling `mongodb-community`. Locally, I am able to connect to the database through the javascript mongodb nodejs driver.

When I run `mongodump --version` I receive:

```
mongodump version: 100.3.1
git version: 32632b931f9c41d8314b75ecc88e551b012b1e30
Go version: go1.15.8
   os: darwin
   arch: amd64
   compiler: gc
```

I am running macOS Catalina version 10.15.7 on a Mid 2012 Retina MacBook Pro.

#### Update

I've now tried the `mongodump` command while using a VPN service and it works.

#### Update 2

After 24 hours the `mongodump` command started working again. I believe it was a problem with my internet provider's firewall (or other) not allowing the command to connect to the MongoDB Atlas server.

Comment: I switched from my home wifi to mobile hotspot and it worked

Comment: In my case I didn't do much on the home-run server. The command started working after about 1 month (noticed from daily scheduled jenkins job log)

Answer (score 0):

The right solution is to whitelist your current IP address in Network Access tab of a cluster.
Steps:

1. Go to `Network Access` tab
2. Click `+ ADD IP ADDRESS` button
3. Enter your current IP address in **Access List Entry** field.
4. Confirm