# mongodump error "Failed: can't create session: could not connect to server:"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodump

I can successfully connect with my mongodb locally with self-signed certificates. Security authorization is set to "disabled" under mongo config and TLS is enabled. Using the `mongodump` command locally

```
mongodump --ssl --authenticationDatabase admin --host=127.0.0.1 --port=27017 -u=admin -p=821ewuyuiuw3! --sslPEMKeyFile=/etc/ssl/mongodb.pem --sslCAFile=/etc/ssl/rootCA.pem --archive=/home/backups/mongodump.gz --gzip
```

The admin user exists despite the fact I disabled the authorization. I get the same error without the credentials also.

I always get the error :

```
2021-12-03T14:58:29.420+0200    Failed: can't create session: could not connect to server: server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: Single, Servers: [{ Addr: 127.0.0.1:27017, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: x509: cannot validate certificate for 127.0.0.1 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs }, ] }
```

I tried also using `export GODEBUG=x509ignoreCN=0` without success. Any solution to this?

Comment: did you solved?

Comment: @Ermal yes, do you have the same problem?

Comment: yes. I don't know if I need to configure --ssl or anything else. But I can't connect through the command line either. (`mongodb://localhost:27017/novi_dedicated --ssl --authenticationDatabase admin `). Can you answer to your own question? If it will solve my issue I will set as answered.

Comment: @Ermal yes I will doit tomorrow, currently I am out of my office

Comment: maybe not relevant to your question, but I had to make sure in Atlas that my Network Access had whitelisted Ips from the host I was executing the command

Comment: For MongoDB Atlas, refer this solution -
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77227320/6918881

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work with both of the following commands. It seems that it was needed the parameter  **--tlsInsecure**

```
mongodump --ssl  --host=127.0.0.1 --port=27017  --sslPEMKeyFile=/etc/ssl/mongoCer/mongodb.pem --sslCAFile=/etc/ssl/mongoCer/rootCA.pem --archive=./mongo-daily-backups/mongodump-date_2020-11-16_time_20-37-11.gz --gzip --tlsInsecure
```

and

```
mongodump --ssl  --host=127.0.0.1 --port=27017 --archive=./mongo-daily-backups/mongodump-date_2020-11-16_time_20-37-11.gz --gzip --tlsInsecure
```

Comment: Thanks a hundert times! I always had only the `--tlsInsecure` option, but it did not work until I added the `--ssl` option.

Answer (score 0):

i recently had the same issue on my server, because I change the hostname of OS, so check your hostname. in ubuntu:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

make sure it had your localhost value=127.0.0.1

OR also you can test your command by just simply define the host value

```
sudo mongodump --host=127.0.0.1 --port=27017 --db mydb
```